# What is the best community for website recommendations?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I was looking for a community to ask a question for a website recommendation but can't find one. What is the best or closest community for these questions?

Comment: If you're looking for a website related to the topic of some existing SE site, you might want to try asking in that site's [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com). Even if the main site doesn't allow recommendation questions, chat tends to be a lot more relaxed. of course, not all sites really have active chat communities, but usually there's at least a *few* regulars that occasionally check out the chat.

Answer (score 2):

There are no Stack sites which really openly welcome "recommendations".
It's a grey area as it easily brings about "opinion" and this is especially troublesome when asking for specific 3rd party tools or, as you need, an external website.

Your question would likely begin "What is the best website for..", and how does one define "the best" without some level of opinion?
And opinions don't really bring about definitive answers, which is what Stack's Q&A format requires.

---

Also, you've not provided the *topic* of your requirement. e.g. Do you want a website for coding, help with cooking, physics, etc?

Comment: Have you forgotten about the Software Recommendation site?

Comment: That is a very specific site with an even stricter policy on asking questions. That levels out the opinion based part a bit. I see it as a test though.

Comment: @LukeDavis As a regular user of SR - I can tell you that a question seeking a *web-app* would be on topic as long as you specifically say what you want - it can't be a vague question. It really does depend on what you mean by 'website recommendation'.

Comment: @LukeDavis "*Have you forgotten about the Software Recommendation site*" If you knew about that, what not put it in your question? Besides, the keywords there are "*software* recommendations" and you asked specifically for "*website* recommendations". Websites are not software. Perhaps you should be a little more clear in your question?

Comment: @James : website can be software : just check out things like office 365 or newer adobe products. This software the only difference is it’s running on a web server and accessed through a web browser. Google decided to shut down chrome apps stating that today’s web software can also work offiline *(while you still use a website in the address bar)*. The line between website and installed software is really thin.

Comment: [Webapps SE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) can't be used for recommending websites that can help solving specific issues? For example I need a website to identify the objects in a collection of images

Comment: @user2284570 "website can be software" Websites "can have" software, but they are still websites with whatever function or utility they provide still being bound in a website. And in their generally accepted definitions, I think websites and software have well recognised differences. "only difference is it’s running on a web server and accessed through a web browser" - so "a website" then?